# How to get value from multiple tables but the value should be min and group wise

Tags: mysql

How to get value from multiple Table that should be minimum and group wise

Like: 
I have Three tables

```
          Table1                              Table3        
|   ID  |   GPN |   PKGID   |           |   GPN |   Amt |
|   1   |   A   |   PKG01   |           |   A   |   10  |
|   2   |   B   |   PKG02   |           |   A   |   15  |
|   3   |   C   |   PKG03   |           |   A   |   20  |
|   4   |   D   |   PKG04   |           |   A   |   25  |
                                        |   A   |   65  |
                                        |   A   |   30  |
-----------------------------           |   B   |   17  |
                                        |   D   |   90  |
                                        |   B   |   20  |
         Table2                         |   B   |   40  |
|   GPN |   Date        |               |   D   |   60  |
|   A   |   2016-09-10  |               |   B   |   80  |
|   A   |   2016-09-18  |               |   B   |   100 |
|   B   |   2016-09-10  |               |   C   |   3   |
|   B   |   2016-09-11  |               |   C   |   6   |
|   B   |   2016-09-12  |               |   C   |   9   |
|   C   |   2016-10-12  |               |   C   |   12  |
|   C   |   2016-10-13  |               |   C   |   15  |
|   C   |   2016-10-14  |               |   D   |   7   |
|   D   |   2016-09-10  |               |   D   |   10  |
|   D   |   2016-10-13  |               |   D   |   13  |
```

And i have to get values from three of table so how can i do that.

For Example

Date = 2016-09-10

and i have to get values behalf of that 
so result should contain all groups min value.

As Result

```
|   ID  |   PKGID   |   GPN |       Amt |   Date        |
|   1   |   PKG01   |   A   |       10  |   2016-09-10  |
|   2   |   PKG02   |   B   |       17  |   2016-09-10  |
|   4   |   PKG04   |   D   |       7   |   2016-09-10  |
```

Comment: select your date from table2, join to your other tables off of the GPN and use the MIN function on the AMT column... you can google your way through this easily and learn a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this too

```
SELECT t1.*, MIN(t3.Amt) as Amt, t2.Date
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.GPN= t2.GPN
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.GPN= t3.GPN
WHERE t2.Date  = '2016-09-10' 
GROUP BY t1.GPN
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be this

```
select table.id, table1.PKGID, table1.GPN, min(table3.Amt), table2.`date`
from table1 
inner join table3 on table1.GPN= table3.GPN
inner join table2 on table1.GPN= table2.GPN
where date(table2.date )  = str_to_date('2016-09-10', '%Y-%m-%d') 
group by table1.GPN, table.id, table1.PKGID, table2.`date`
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge you have solved all inner join confusion Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. First get the `MIN(Amt)` by grouping and then perform a `JOIN`

```
select t1.*,
xxx.Amt,
t2.`Date`
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.GPN = t2.GPN
join (select GPN, min(Amt) as Amt from table3 group by GPN) xxx
on t1.GPN = xxx.GPN;
```